# Error: "Hit <Return> to see next plot: " in r

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
frame()
Y = read.table("Yfile.txt",header=T,row.names=NULL,sep='')
X =  read.table("Xfile.txt",header=F,sep='')

plot(Y$V1~X$V1,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27))
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~X$V2,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='red')
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~Y$V3,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='blue')
par(new=T)
```

All is well and I get the 3 graphs on the same plot. However, when I want to divide X$V1, X$V2 and X$V3 to normalise the data such that

```
plot(Y$V1~X$V1/Y$V2,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27))
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~X$V2/Y$V2,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='red')
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~Y$V3/Y$V2,pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='blue')
par(new=T)
```

I get the message

> Hit Return to see next plot:

and the graphs just won't show in the same plot. Could anybody tell me what is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use arithmetic operations in formula you have to use `I()` functions. So

```
plot(Y$V1~I(X$V1/Y$V2),pch=20,xlim=c(0,27))
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~I(X$V2/Y$V2),pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='red')
par(new=T)
plot(Y$V1~I(Y$V3/Y$V2),pch=20,xlim=c(0,27),col='blue')
par(new=T)
```

works.

Following help page to `formula`:

> To avoid this confusion, the function
>   `I()` can be used to bracket those
>   portions of a model formula where the
>   operators are used in their arithmetic
>   sense. For example, in the formula `y
>   ~ a + I(b+c)`, the term `b+c` is to be
>   interpreted as the sum of `b` and `c`.

---

Edit. You could do it without formula in one command:

```
plot(c(X$V1/Y$V2, X$V2/Y$V2, Y$V3/Y$V2), rep(Y$V1, 3),
    pch=20, xlim=c(0,27),
    col=rep(c("black", "red", "blue"), each=30)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Amazing I couldn't find anything on search engines regarding something as basic as this!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you get the error, but using `points` instead of `plot` for the second and third graph is a much more elegant solution (and gets rid of those `par` calls)